# Adjust JS to work on content after it's been dynamically loaded through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having an issue where, after dynamically attempting to load content in through AJAX, the content isn't responsive to the JS code that it used to be.

Here's a jsfiddle of this navigation bar working *before* trying to dynamically loading it using AJAX... http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/m107L4mh/

But now it's just nonresponsive. I asked for similar help before and attempted to add proper event handlers, but clearly I'm still struggling.

Please help if you can.

Thank you.

init.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                var nav, content, fetchAndInsert;

                nav = $('nav#main');
                content = $('section#content');


                //Fetches and inserts content into the container
                fetchAndInsert = function(href) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost/TTValid/content/' + href.split('/').pop(),
                        method: 'GET',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            content.html(data);
                        }                    
                    });
                }; 


                //User goes back/forward 
                $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                    fetchAndInsert(location.pathname);
                });


                nav.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');

                    //Manipulate history
                    history.pushState(null, null, href);

                    //Fetch and insert content
                    fetchAndInsert(href);


                    e.preventDefault();            
                });

});
```

page1.js

```
$(function () {

    var container = $('.navbar');

    $(document).on('click', '.navbar ul li a', function(event) { 
        $('.navbar > li:first-child > a').text($(this).text());
        $('.navbar > li > ul').addClass('hidden');
        $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(100);
        $('.navbar ul li.gone').removeClass("gone");
        $(event.target).closest("li").addClass("gone");    
    });

    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.navbar > li', function(event) { 
        $(this).find('ul').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.ActiveListItem', function(event) { 
        $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(300);
    });



    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            $('.navbar li ul').slideUp(300);
        }
    });

});
```

page1.php

```
<?php
require 'views/TTheader.php';
?>

<section id="content">
    <?php require 'content/TTpage1.php'; ?>
</section>

<?php
require 'views/TTfooter.php';
?>
```

content/page1.php

```
<div id="navbarcontainer">
                <ul class="navbar cf">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="ActiveListItem">Category</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Movie</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Book</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Game</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Activity</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Misc</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: I create another fiddle that the content generated by the script (loading content via AJAX simulation) and the dropdown works file. http://jsfiddle.net/50rrrd7p/. What is the problem? You using `on` handler (except the `mouseup` event) so it's good.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. On my computer, the dropdown menu is just isn't responsive. I tested it on another computer and the dropdown menu is functioning *but* the AJAX part was malfunctioning. Not sure what is causing the errors in either case....

Comment: In your computer my jsfiddle was worked?

Comment: Yes. It works on both computers (and with no differences between computers).

Comment: So, it's something else. Can you provide a public URL of this project?

Comment: Gladly. This is a link to a zip of the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7_gP8gVsU92UTFNM3NpSTFBcTQ/view?usp=sharing I run it with Apache running on XAMPP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88565/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-matthew).

Comment: Well.. There are some mistakes in your code. Check this code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_6v7nVfuvmdzBoWS1nbklyQUk/view.
I can not list all the problems and it is irrelevant to others.

Comment: Wow, amazing work, thank you!! I'm very grateful for all your help!

Comment: You are very welcome :)